# How to get a namespace path for my library on bintray(jcenter)?

Tags: android, maven, namespaces, bintray, jcenter

I have an android library with dependency e.g: in.ac.mylibrary:libraryname:1.0.0

Now how do I make sure that no one else uses the namespace ( in this example '**in.ac.mylibrary**' ) that I have used for their libraries i.e. how do I own this namespace or groupId?

Is the namespace by default given to the user who first uses it to publish a library to **jcenter**, or is there some ownership criteria for the groupId/namespace?

Answer (score 1):

In order to claim the domain ownership of the package path “in/ac/mylibrary/libraryname” you need to submit a JCenter inclusion request from your Bintray account. Once the request is approved, the package path will be visible in the https://jcenter.bintray.com/ .You can refer to the below link for more information https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/BT/Central+Repositories+New+UI#CentralRepositoriesNewUI-JCenter